# The Function getDatabase() Called Recursively error?

Tags: sqlite, android-asynctask, sqliteopenhelper

I am Using SQLiteDatabase to store data that was bought in background in the AsyncTask doInBackground() method, sometimes if the recieved data was not in the database , I insert data, If the recieved data was present already and unread I mark that data as unread...
But it says getDatabase recursively called in doInBackground Method()...
Is it problem because I performed operations on a Background Thread or Some Other...
This app scrapes news from website and displays it in app and also adds to the sqlite database if the news was seen it marks as old..

```
2019-07-07 16:16:46.664 27223-27276/com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege, PID: 27223
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:365)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:246)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:206)
        at com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege.NewsDbHelper.insertUrl(NewsDbHelper.java:36)
        at com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege.NewsDbHelper.onCreate(NewsDbHelper.java:26)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:310)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:206)
        at com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege.NewsDbHelper.urlExists(NewsDbHelper.java:59)
        at com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege.NewsFragment$TaskLoader.doInBackground(NewsFragment.java:144)
        at com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege.NewsFragment$TaskLoader.doInBackground(NewsFragment.java:111)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Here is the Db Helper Class

```
package com.github.chillmonk2.mycollege;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class NewsDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "news.db";
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "newsIndex";
   public String COL_0 = "URL";
   public String COL_1 = "STATUS";
   SQLiteDatabase db;
   //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   public NewsDbHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null ,1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       String createTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                           COL_0 + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," +
                           COL_1 + " INT );";
       db.execSQL(createTable);
       insertUrl("EMPTY");

   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   }
   public int insertUrl(String url)
   {
       db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(COL_0,url);
       values.put(COL_1,"0");//0 - Unread
       int result = (int)db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
       return result;
   }
   public int updateUrl(String Url)
   {
       db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(COL_0,Url);
       values.put(COL_1,1);
       int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,COL_0 +"=?",new String[]{Url});
       return result;
   }
   public int deleteUrl(String Url)
   {

       int result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL_0 + "=?",new String[]{Url});
       return result;
   }
   boolean urlExists(String Url){
      db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       String sql = "select * from "+TABLE_NAME + " where "+ COL_0 +"=?";
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{Url});
       int count = cursor.getCount();
       if (count>=1)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   int getUrlStatus(String url)
   {
       //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       String sql = "select "+COL_1+" from "+TABLE_NAME + " where "+ COL_0 +"=?";
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,new String[]{url});
       int status = -1;
       while (cursor.moveToFirst())
       {
           status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_1));
       }
       return status;
   }


}
```

This is the Part of Code in NewsFragment.java class

```
 @Override
        protected ArrayList<NewsObject> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = "http://rvrjc.ac.in/";
            ArrayList<NewsObject> mList = new ArrayList<NewsObject>();
            Document document;
            try {
                Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"Main Activity");
                document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements lnews = document.select("ul.newsticker li b");
                Elements bnews = document.select("div#galleryimage p");
                //Get the title of the website
                for (Element news : lnews) {//latest news Section
                    String s = "New";
                    String descNews = news.select("p").text();
                    String newsUrl = news.select("a").attr("href");
                    if (newsUrl.startsWith("http")) {
                        //do nothing
                        if(!db.urlExists(newsUrl)){
                            db.insertUrl(newsUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int status = db.getUrlStatus(newsUrl);
                            if(status==1){//read
                                s = "Old";
                            }
                            else
                                s = "New";
                        }
                       mList.add(new NewsObject(descNews, newsUrl,s));
                    } else
                        mList.add(new NewsObject(descNews, url ,s));
                }
                for(Element news:bnews){

                    String descNews = news.select("p").text();
                    String newsGif = news.select("p img").attr("src");
                    String newsStatus = "Old" ;
                    if(newsGif.equals("new.gif"))
                    {

                        newsStatus = "New";
                        //System.out.println("News Status changed");
                    }
                    String newsUrl = news.select("a").attr("href");
                    if(newsUrl.startsWith("http"))
                    {
                        if(!db.urlExists(newsUrl)){
                            db.insertUrl(newsUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int status = db.getUrlStatus(newsUrl);
                            if(status==1){//read
                                newsStatus = "Old";
                            }
                            else
                                newsStatus = "New";
                        }
                        //do nothing
                        mList.add(new NewsObject(descNews,newsUrl,newsStatus));
                    }
                    else
                        mList.add(new NewsObject(descNews,url,newsStatus));
                }



            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("TAG",""+mList);
            return mList;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<NewsObject> newsArrayList) {
            super.onPostExecute(newsArrayList);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("TAG","Inside onPostExecute"+newsArrayList);
            mNewsAdapter.addAll(newsArrayList);
            mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 insertUrl("EMPTY");
```

Is the cause as you are trying to use the **NewsDbHelper** instance to open the database whilst it is still part way through opening the database.

- When you construct an instance, the database isn't opened. It's not until you try to access the database that is it opened. It is during this open that the onCreate method is called (if the database didn't previously exist) to create the database, so you can't try to use `this.getWritabaleDatabase` as it's still in the processing of doing another `this.getWritableDatabase` (*or getReadableDatabase instead of getWritableDatabase*)

Instead you could use

```
db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "VALUES ('EMPTY',0)");
```

- **Note** the code is in-principle code, it has not been run or tested and may therefore contains some errors.